# Is this a mathematics field?

Tags: universal-algebra

When I'm studying, I often find myself searching for the minimal conditions to define something. A simple example is: to define a circumference in a plane you need 3 points or 1 point and a distance, or even 4 points, but this last one is not "efficient" (also, not all 4 sets of points define a circumference).

This way of thinking can also be applied to other concepts like specific algebras, that is my main focus. For example, what is the minimum conditions needed to define a group.

I was wondering, is there a math field that studies this kinds of problems?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: by "circumference" do you mean circle?

Comment: You may be interested in [fractal dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension#Examples)